# HTTP static resources caching forever stategy

Tags: android, http, picasso, okhttp, http-caching

In [Effective Android HTTP](https://plus.google.com/+JesseWilson/posts/QmyisEuJB7e) Jesse Wilson mentioned the following:

> Serving static resources like images?
>   Use a permanent URL and let it cache forever

I am using [Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso) with a specific [OkHttp](https://github.com/square/okhttp) instance for fetching and caching images. I am wondering how to setup the `let it cache forever` strategy?

I can only think about overriding the HTTP cache control header max-stale (`Cache-Control: max-stale=`)with the highest possible value, is there another (better) way?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Best way is to configure your server to include a long max-age. For example, specify 365 days with this header:

```
Cache-Control: max-age=31536000
```

If you want to enable unlimited caching on the client, you can use a long max-stale:

```
Cache-Control: max-stale=31536000
```

Comment: Is there a reason this is considered better than a long "Expires"?

Comment: It’s preferred by RFC 7234, the HTTP caching spec. “If a response includes a Cache-Control field with the max-age directive (Section 5.2.2.8), a recipient MUST ignore the Expires field.”