# How do I prevent the images from being requested on Shift+F5?

Tags: http, caching, cache-control, clientside-caching

I have a website with a page containing a lot of images. Those images will *never* change on the server (if they change, the URI on the page referencing them will have a different version parameter, in an URI such as http://cdn.example.com/image1.jpg?v=123).

The images are served with `Cache-Control: max-stale=31536000, public` header as advised in [an answer on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23260323/240613).

`ETag` header is disabled, as recommended in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19535835/240613).

When I press <kbd>F5</kbd> in Chrome, everything works as expected: the page reloads, and there are no requests for images. However, when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>, the browser does the requests to the server.

I want it to behave as for the favicon: do a request to the server only when explicitly asked (that is a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> *on the specific image*), and avoid a roundtrip to the server when I do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> on a page containing the images.

Is it possible?

If yes, what headers should I put in the response?

Notes:

- The developer console remains *closed* during the tests.
- The content is directly served from a server; no reverse proxies.
- When the image is requested after I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> on a page, the *request* contains `Cache-Control: no-cache`, making it impossible to respond with HTTP 304.

Comment: https://www.greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc8246.html might be of interest.

Comment: Possibly you could replace the `src` attribute with a custom `data-src` attribute, then use javascript to load the images.  Depending on how the javascript was written, you could probably ensure that ctrl+f5 did not cause a redownload of the images.  Admittedly, using this technique will break your site for noscript users.